# How to use css in media-queries with a javascript condition?

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

I'm working with this organizational chart https://codepen.io/erinesullivan/pen/LLoXoL. Basically what I want to do is to use the css classes inside the media query if a condition is true. Any easy way to do it? This is what the classes I have to use if the condition is true look like.

```
@media only screen and ( min-width: 64em ) {

    ol.organizational-chart {
        margin-left: -1em;
        margin-right: -1em;
    }

    /* PRIMARY */
    ol.organizational-chart > li > div {
        display: inline-block;
        float: none;
        margin: 0 1em 1em 1em;
        vertical-align: bottom;
    }

    ol.organizational-chart > li > div:only-of-type {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        width: calc((100% / 1) - 2em - 4px);
    }

    ol.organizational-chart > li > div:first-of-type:nth-last-of-type(2),
    ol.organizational-chart > li > div:first-of-type:nth-last-of-type(2) ~ div {
        width: calc((100% / 2) - 2em - 4px);
    }

    ol.organizational-chart > li > div:first-of-type:nth-last-of-type(3),
    ol.organizational-chart > li > div:first-of-type:nth-last-of-type(3) ~ div {
        width: calc((100% / 3) - 2em - 4px);
    }

    ol.organizational-chart > li > div:first-of-type:nth-last-of-type(4),
    ol.organizational-chart > li > div:first-of-type:nth-last-of-type(4) ~ div {
        width: calc((100% / 4) - 2em - 4px);
    }

    ol.organizational-chart > li > div:first-of-type:nth-last-of-type(5),
    ol.organizational-chart > li > div:first-of-type:nth-last-of-type(5) ~ div {
        width: calc((100% / 5) - 2em - 4px);
    }
    /* SECONDARY */
    ol.organizational-chart > li > ol {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
    }

    ol.organizational-chart > li > ol:before,
    ol.organizational-chart > li > ol > li:before {
        height: 1em!important;
        left: 50%!important;
        top: 0!important;
        width: 3px!important;
    }

    ol.organizational-chart > li > ol:after {
        display: none;
    }

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Write the CSS in a different class. And add that class only when the condition is true?

Answer (score 0):

such expressions are suitable for this task:

```
window.matchMedia("(min-width: 500px)");
```

for check:

```
const mq = window.matchMedia( "(min-width: 500px)" );
    if (mq.matches) {
        console.log('window width is at least 500px');
    } else {
        console.log('window width is less than 500px')
    }
```

Comment: Hello Serg, thanks for your answer. Actually I have to use the code inside the media query if another condition is true. In particular, I have an array, and if this array has more than 5 elements, I would like to use the code inside the media query. I think that matchMedia can't solve my problem :/